# Charge resonance

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, electrical-resistance, resonance, inductance

In an RLC circuit in series, there is something called charge resonance given by $f_r=√(f_0^2-R^2/(8π^2 L^2 ))$
. What does it represent? How is it derived? I am familiar with the resonance that says that the reactance of $L$ equals the reactance of $C$. $f_0=1/(2π√LC)$.

Comment: You can have resonance in an RLC circuit but I never heard it called "charge" resonance. Cite your reference

Comment: There is no $C$ in your formula. What is $f_0$?

Comment: f_0 is the natural resonance frequency 1/(2.pi.sqrt(LC))?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my poor english. French is my native language.

There are two types of resonance:

- current resonance : which corresponds to the maximum of the amplitude of the voltage $Ri$ for the resistor. The resonant frequency is the natural frequency you indicate.
- Charge resonance : corresponds to the maximum of the voltage $Q / C$ for the capacitor. The resonant frequency is the second frequency you indicate.